# Nodejs Global Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very basic function that looks like this, it is in a file called `functions.js`

```
function echo(input){
    process.stdout.write(echo);
}
```

When I add the file and call `echo()` like so:

Main file:

```
require("functions.js");
require("another_file.js");
```

**another_file.js**

```
echo("hello!");
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: echo is not defined
```

Is there a way for me to make a function that is global like that without havingin to use `exports`?

Comment: try `echo = function echo(input){ ... }`

Comment: @Plato: better be explicit by doing `global.echo = …`. Assigning to uninitialised variables is an error (in strict mode)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Inside `functions.js` you'll have access to node's `global` variable, which is like the `window` variable in a browser. As Plato suggested in a comment, you can add this to the global by simply doing `echo = function echo(input){ ... }`. However, this will throw an error if you're using strict mode, which is intended to catch common mistakes (like accidentally creating global variables).

One way to safely add `echo` as a global is to add it to the global `global` variable.

```
"use strict";

global.echo = function echo(input) {
    process.stdout.write(input);
}
```

I think generally using `exports` is better practice, because otherwise once `functions.js` is included (from any other file) you'll have access to `echo` in every file and it can be hard to track down where it's coming from.

To do so you would need to have your `functions.js` look more like:

```
"use strict";

module.exports.echo = function echo(input) {
    process.stdout.write(input);
}
```

Then in your main script do something like:

```
"use strict";

var functions = require("./functions.js");

functions.echo("Hello, World");
```

Comment: You don't need that IEFE, node already has a global `global` variable. It might even not work at all because `this` in the module scope is not the global object iirc.

Comment: Oops! You're right - `this` is not `global` nor `module`. Editing my answer now

Comment: Should have done some testing before. Also found out that "use strict"; doesn't cause it to throw an error if you just do `echo = ...` but also doesn't set it to the global (I'm more familiar with the browser environment than node). Edited answer to reflect that

Comment: Wait, `echo = …` doesn't throw in strict mode? Then there must be a declaration somewhere. odd. edit: I've tested this now in node, and it does throw indeed.

Comment: @bergi, ah, looks like i was saying `function echo() { }; echo = ...`...changing it to just `echo = function echo() { }` does cause it to throw in strict mode